# Calling "imdbapi.com" with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the movie poster from IMDB according to the title of a movie, in a function.

I have tried :

```
function getPoster(title)
{
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.imdbapi.com/?t=" + title,
      datatype: "json",
      success: return data
    });
}
```

But I don't really know how to "return" data I got from .ajax() ...

edit IMDBapi returns a json dataset, as in :

```
{"Title":"Jurassic Park","Year":"1993","Rated":"PG-13","Released":"11 Jun 1993","Genre":"Action, Adventure, Family, Sci-Fi","Director":"Steven Spielberg","Writer":"Michael Crichton, Michael Crichton","Actors":"Sam Neill, Laura Dern, Jeff Goldblum, Richard Attenborough","Plot":"During a preview tour, a theme park suffers a major power breakdown that allows its cloned dinosaur exhibits to run amok.","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTc2NDIxNTQyNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzIwMzM3MQ@@._V1._SX320.jpg","Runtime":"2 hrs 7 mins","Rating":"7.9","Votes":"159458","ID":"tt0107290","Response":"True"}
```

edit2 :
This worked :

```
for(var i in titles)
{
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.imdbapi.com/?t=" + titles[i],
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data) {
        $('body').append(data.Poster+'<br />');
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: There is a cross domain issue there....

Comment: so, the poster is the following piece of data, right? `"Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTc2NDIxNTQyNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzIwMzM3MQ@@._V1._SX320.jpg"`

Comment: @SLaks, it does not even work with jsonp: http://jsfiddle.net/xVAbm/

Comment: @Neal: If you spell correctly, it does work.  http://jsfiddle.net/xVAbm/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

AJAX is **asynchronous**; you only get a reply from the server after your function returns.

Instead, you can make your function accept a callback, just like `$.ajax` does.

Comment: Oooooh *that's* why there's no return but a callback ! :)

Comment: Yes.  If something seems unusually hard to do, there is usually a reason.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
function getPoster(title)
{
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.imdbapi.com/?t=" + title,
      datatype: "jsonp",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);  
            do_some_function(data);
        }
    });

}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xVAbm/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function(data){
  // do what you want with the data here..
  alert(data.Title);
}
```

To avoid cross domain restrictions (*since the API seems to support it*) use

```
function getPoster(title)
{
    $.getJSON('http://www.imdbapi.com/?t=' + title + '&callback=?' ,
      function(data){alert(data.Title);}
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function getPoster(title){

$.getJSON('http://www.imdbapi.com/?t=' + title, function(data) {
  var items = [];

    $.each(data, function(key, val) {

    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');

    });

    $('<ul/>', {

        'class': 'my-new-list',
        html: items.join('')
       }).appendTo('body');

    });
}
```

You could receive and list data as so.